# conversion of datetime Field to string in django queryset.values_list()

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-models

I have a queryset like:

```
qs = MyModel.objects.filter(name='me').values_list('activation_date')
```

here **activation_date** is **DateTimeField** in models.
When I download excel sheet from this qs I am not getting activation date in **string format.**
How can I convert this field('activation_date') in string or how to typecast it in qs?

Comment: you are missing `flat=True`

Answer (score 36):

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#datetimefield

> A date and time, represented in Python by a datetime.datetime instance.

You can get a string representation of a `DateTimeField` casting it directly:

```
str(obj)
# obj = qs[0][0] ? or qs[0][1] ?
```

You'll get result like this (in this example I use `datetime.datetime.now()` since a `DateTimeField` is represented by `datetime.datetime` is the same behavior):

```
>>> now = datetime.datetime.now()
>>> str(now)
'2013-06-26 00:14:26.260524'
```

if you want less information or formatted in other mode you can use `strftime()` function for format them. see:

```
>>> now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')
'2013-06-26 00:14'
```

Comment: Is there any way to get the month directly in text time (e.g. 11 = November)?

Comment: `datetime.datetime.now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')` -> `AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'strftime'`

Comment: @ar2015 `now` is a function, try this: `datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')`

Answer (score 32):

[`extra()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#extra) is an old API that Django aims to deprecate at some point in the future. I would avoid using it.

Try the following instead:

```
from django.db.models import F, Func, Value, CharField

qs.annotate(
  formatted_date=Func(
    F('date'),
    Value('dd.MM.yyyy hh:mm'),
    function='to_char',
    output_field=CharField()
  )
)
```

This works only with a database that supports the `to_char` [date type formatting function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/functions-formatting.html). `Postgres` provides this function by default.

- If you use a `MSSQL` backend you could swap `to_char` with `FORMAT`.
- For `MySQL` use `DATE_FORMAT`.
- For `Oracle` consult their
  documentation, etc.

After the queryset is evaluated this will add the annotation `formatted_date` to each object in the queryset that is returned.

Comment: This was very helpful, thanks. However, the function for MySQL is `DATE_FORMAT`. `FORMAT` is for regular numbers, not dates.

Comment: I think you missread my answer. I was taking about Microsoft SQL not MySQL for the ``FORMAT`` function. I adapted my answer and added the function for MySQL as you pointed out. Thanks!

Comment: If you use this often, you can avoid having to type output_field and function all the time by defining a function by extending Func.  I set arity = 2, function = 'to_char' (for postgres, mind you!), output_field = models.CharField()

Comment: Awesome, idea, can you provide a link how exactly you achieved this? Optionally just extend my answer to make this more performant!

Comment: use the format ('dd.MM.yyyy HH:MI') if you are using Postgres db

Answer (score 19):

**`extra` is deprecated in Django 2.0**

That's why I think the best solution to get a stringified datetime is:

```
foo_bar = FooBarModel.objects.annotate(
    str_datetime=Cast(
        TruncSecond('some_datetime_field', DateTimeField()), CharField()
    )
).values('str_datetime').first()
```

**The result is**:

```
foo_bar.str_datetime:
(str)'2014-03-28 15:36:55'
```

---

Also I'd like to mention that you can format it as well in any way you want like:

```
from django.db.models import Value

foo_bar = FooBarModel.objects.annotate(
    day=Cast(ExtractDay('some_datetime_field'), CharField()),
    hour=Cast(ExtractHour('some_datetime_field'), CharField()),
    str_datetime=Concat(
        Value('Days: '), 'day', Value(' Hours: '), 'hour', 
        output_field=CharField()
    )
).values('str_datetime').first()
```

**The result is**:

```
foo_bar.str_datetime:
(str)'Days: 28 Hours: 15'
```

Comment: No, `extra` is not deprecated in Django 2.0.  I use it myself even.  They have not set a deadline on its deprecation. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#extra

Comment: The first lines of code gives me a :  django.db.utils.OperationalError: near "None": syntax error

Comment: @Aurélien that is weird. Do you mean `foo_bar = FooBarModel.objects.annotate` is an incorrect statement?

Comment: @MrCyberthrone indeed this is weird, because this code looks fine to me. But if you tried this, an error will pop:

`User.objects.all().annotate(year=Cast(ExtractYear('date_joined'), CharField()),month=Cast(ExtractMonth('date_joined'), CharField()),day=Cast(ExtractDay('date_joined'), CharField()),str_datetime=Concat('day', Value(' / '), 'month', Value(' / '), 'year', output_field=CharField())).values('str_datetime').first()`

returns: `sqlite3.OperationalError: near "None": syntax error`

Comment: @Aurélien please have a look at https://i.imgur.com/gM9uveE.png 
I pasted your code and it works great. Maybe the problem is in Sqlite3. I'm using MySQL.
If you find out the problem please let me know. That's interesting

Comment: @MrCyberthrone, I try on a Postgres db, and this is the message  : https://imgur.com/a/pnV65JL

Comment: @Aurélien hmm. Could you please provide a file with a dump of Users so I could test it?
Along with a Django version you are using and imports of these `Concat`, `Value`, etc. Maybe a wrong import path is specified

Comment: This is my import

 `from django.db.models import Value, CharField `

 `from django.db.models.functions import Cast, Concat, ExtractDay, ExtractMonth, ExtractYear `

Using the version 1.11.4

Comment: FYI, I created a question about that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51174993/extract-on-date-django-db-utils-operationalerror-near-none-syntax-error

Answer (score 10):

If you are using Postgres, you can do it like this ([date format options here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/functions-formatting.html)).  The solution is database dependent, but it sure beats looping though a long list in Python land after your perform the query.

```
qs = MyModel.objects.filter(name='me')
qs = qs.extra(select={'datestr':"to_char(activation_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')"})
qs = qs.values_list('datestr')
```

I am sure MySQL has some equivalent function as Postgres's to_char, but you'll have to find that on your own as I am not a MySQL guy.

Answer (score 6):

Very surprised to see that no one suggested the cast to a simple `TextField` (note, I'm using Postgres so I can't confirm for other RDBMSes):

```
from django.db.models.functions import Cast
from django.db.models import TextField

queryset = FooBarModel.objects.values(my_datetime=Cast('some_datetime_field', TextField()))
foo_bar = queryset.first()
foo_bar['my_datetime']
>>> u'2019-10-03 17:59:37.979578+00'
```

It similarly also works fine for nested fields:

```
queryset = FooBarModel.objects.values(Cast('baz__some_datetime_field', TextField()))
```

Alternatively, a custom `Func` can also be used (also specific to Postgres here, but can be modified for any other RDBMS):

```
class FullDateTimeCast(Func):
   """
   Coerce an expression to a new field type.
   """
   function = 'TO_CHAR'
   template = '%(function)s(%(expressions)s, \'FMDay, Month DD, YYYY at HH12:MI:SS AM\')'

queryset = FooBarModel.objects.values(my_datetime=FullDateTimeCast('some_datetime_field', TextField()))
foo_bar = queryset.first()
foo_bar['my_datetime']
>>> u' Thursday, October 03, 2019 at 17:59:37 PM'
```

Comment: I used this trick on sqlite database, and it works well!

Comment: It's FullDateTimeCast that worked without TextField()

Answer (score 5):

```
qs = MyModel.objects.filter(name='me')
qs = qs.extra(select={'datestr':"DATE_FORMAT(activation_date, '%Y-%m-%d')"})
qs = qs.values_list('datestr')
```

Comment: second line should be:

``qs = qs.extra(select={'datestr':"DATE_FORMAT(activation_date, '%%Y-%%m-%%d')"})
``

Comment: Yes, should be double % signs in the date format: '%%Y-%%m-%%d', otherwise, you will get error.

Answer (score 2):

You can also convert the date in queryset to string using `map` function. Example:

```
qs = MyModel.objects.filter(name='me').values_list('activation_date', flat=True)
data = map(str, qs)
```

Comment: This is not scalable with large queries

Answer (score 2):

I did it this way

```
.annotate(date_str=ExpressionWrapper(
            Func(F('date'), Value('%d/%m/%Y %H:%i'), function='DATE_FORMAT'), output_field=CharField()
        ))
```

Comment: `cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-00904: "DATE_FORMAT": `invalid identifier. Where did you imported the DATE_FORMAT.

Comment: he is probably using an mssql backend

Answer (score 1):

If you are doing this once, refer to Yannic Hamann's answer. However if you find yourself converting to str from the database a lot, you can define the Func as a class to avoid having to type output_field and function a bunch.

```
class DateToChar(models.Func):
    """
    Custom Func expression to convert datetimes to str's in database query

    Params for initializer
    ------
    expression_1
        expression resulting in a date: ex: F('date')
    expression_2
        Format string as an expression: Value('YYYY-MM-DD')
    """
    arity = 2
    function = 'to_char'
    output_field = models.CharField()
```

Note that function will change depending on the database backend. This is written for Postgres.

This can be used like

```
qs = qs.annotate(date_str=DateToChar(F('date'), Value('YYYY-MM-DD'))
```

or with any expression that results in a date/datetime/Integer/Float/Decimal field (See [Postgres to_char](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/functions-formatting.html). Varies by database) and an expression resulting in a CharField or TextField.

See [Func](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/expressions/#func-expressions) documentation for more information

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue then I solved this in the following way:

```
from django.db.models.functions import Substr

list(  Model.objects.values('when_date').annotate(date= Substr('when_date',1,10), total=Sum('amount')) )
```

(Django 4.1, python 3.10)