# How do I extract day,month,year from a DateField object?

Tags: python, django

I have a model that contains a field 'expire_date' of type DateField.  I want to define a method that looks like this:

```
def get_expire_date_str(self):
        return "{0}-{1}-{2}".format(self.expire_date.year, self.expire_date.month, self,expire_date.day)
```

I looked through the django docs but I'm still not sure how to access this information.

Comment: This should be a good help:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17085898/conversion-of-datetime-field-to-string-in-django-queryset-values-list

Answer (score 6):

Use [strftime](http://strftime.org/) from the datetime module:

```
date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
#=> '1989-12-06'
```

It's more semantic and its a best practice for when working with dates.

use it this way:

```
def get_expire_date_str(self): 
    return self.expire_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
```

Comment: If I answered your question, can you please accept my answer?