# Populate Month Based on Date Field in Django

Tags: python, django, date, django-models, django-admin

I would like to have a field auto-generate the month based on the date entered before it.

models.py

```
class Projects(models.Model):
    Name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=False) 
    Date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=False)
    Month = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=False)   

        def get_month(self):
            if self.Date:
                self.Month = self.Date.strftime("%B")
                self.save()
```

I saw this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23352305/how-do-i-extract-day-month-year-from-a-datefield-object) on SO and tried it out, but nothing seems to be happening. What am I missing? Do I have to create one of [these](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/fields/#choices)? Thanks.

Comment: I think instead of creating a separate field, you should create a `Month` property on `Projects` model. It will handle the logic of returning the `Month` value based on the `Date` attribute.

Comment: @RahulGupta thank you for your response.  I have not heard of properties until now, and it sounds like this would be the solution. I however can't get it to work. Can you provide an example. I've tried out what was listed in one of the answers.

Comment: After further reading, I know get what you meant by adding it as a property, but if you could read the comment I made in one of the answers, it will explain that this would be used in the admin.py while making an entry into the database.

Comment: You can add the `Month` property in `list_display` or `readonly_fields` tuple in `admin.py` so that this field is displayed in admin. It will just compute the value using `Date` and display it in the admin. You generally define a property when you want to compute a value based on a field or multiple fields without the need of saving it to the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply override your `save` to add the *auto-field* instead of calling `save` in a new method:

```
class Projects(models.Model):
    Name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=False) 
    Date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=False)
    Month = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=False)  

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.Date: 
            self.Month = self.Date.strftime("%B")
        super(Model, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

But the above will make `Month` available only after the instance has been saved.

You can instead create a property, so that `Month` is available from an instance of the model and also prevent adding duplicate info in your DB:

```
class Projects(models.Model):
    Name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=False) 
    Date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=False)

    @property
    def Month(self):
        if self.Date:
            return self.Date.strftime("%B")
        return "No date entry"
```

You can use the property like so:

```
import datetime.date as dt

# import your Projects model
p = Projects(Name='ceuskervin', Date= dt.today())

print(p.Month)
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I was not introduced to properties until reading your response. I tried the 1st option and it works fine. However I couldn't get the 2nd solution to work. Took away Month field but now it's non-existent/not visible.

Comment: How did you try to access `Month`? Remember, you should do this with an instance of the model

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, how would I create an instance of the model? I am still in my `models.py` right?

Comment: Okay I understand now, and that's great, I didn't know that! Just to explain the context I am using it in. It will be used while in the Django admin, while doing manual data entry. I've only seen properties used in `views.py` (novice here). How would I make it appear while someone is adding an entry from the `admin.py` interface?

Comment: I hope you can shed some further light, but I will accept this as an answer since the 1st example works as a temporary solution.

Comment: @ceuskervin There's a good article about using properties in Django models: [How to replace a Django model field with a property](https://www.stavros.io/posts/how-replace-django-model-field-property/). It should help.