# Django query formatting datetime output

Tags: python, django, postgresql, datetime

My Django install uses a PostgreSQL backend.

I am doing the following in a Django view:

```
completedItems = Completed.objects.filter(user_id=1)
return HttpResponse(completedItems.values('item_id','item_name','event_datetime','item_id__item_name'))
```

For the date timefield, this returns:

```
'event_datetime': datetime.datetime(2014, 6, 4, 0, 49, 38, tzinfo=<UTC>)
```

I am trying to serialize the return using json.dumps, and this formatting is giving me grief. What is the best way to reformat the datetime return from the query so I can serialize it properly?

I tried to use:

```
datetime.strptime('event_datetime',"datetime.datetime(%Y, %m, %d, %H, %M, %S, tzinfo=<%Z>)")
```

but it complains that the date does not match the format string.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do. `strptime` is for converting a string to a datetime, but you seem to have a datetime already.

Comment: Ahh, sorry. I left out an important detail. I'm trying to convert the datetime into a string that I can serialize and pass to another app in JSON (this Django app is essentially serving as a REST server). I'm looking for a good way to get a seralizable string from a datetime.

Answer (score 7):

For use "to_char" function PostgreSQL in some queryset possibly via annotate with Func, (from Django 1.8)

```
rows = some_queryset.annotate(str_date=Func(F('date'), Value('DD.MM.YYYY'), function='to_char'))
```

then each item in rows has 'str_date' as string date in format 'DD.MM.YYYY'

- from django.db.models import Func, F, Value
- 'date' in F('date') is field of Model with datetime data

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using .extra to inject PostgreSQL "to_char" to re-format this. This is the solution suggested by PKKid [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17085898/conversion-of-datetime-field-to-string-in-django-queryset-values-list).