# How to get django queryset results with formatted datetime field

Tags: python, django, datetime, django-models

I've Django model which has foreign keys associated with other models. Each model is having same field names(attributes) created_at and updated_at

In every django queryset results I'll be getting datetime values.

```
Model.objects.all().values('created_at')
```

But I want to format the datetime field to "DD-MM-YYYY HH:MM:SS" and trim down the milliseconds in the django query results.

If I use "extra" and and date_trunc_sql like the following command

```
dt = connection.ops.date_trunc_sql('day','created_date')
objects.extra({'date':dt}).values('date')
```

Which works fine. But If I query like the following, its raising ambiguous statement error.

```
objects.extra({'date':dt}).values('date', 'x', 'y', 'z')
```

How to overcome this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Got the solution.

```
data = list(Model.objects.extra(select={'date':"to_char(<DATABASENAME>_<TableName>.created_at, 'YYYY-MM-DD hh:mi AM')"}).values_list('date', flat='true')
```

It's not just tablename.attribute, it should be dbname_tablename.attribute when we have multiple databases(ambiguous)

which will result list of created_at datetime values trimmed to 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM' format.

Comment: Great answer but should be `appname_modelname` or just `tablename`

Comment: if you don't have relation there isn't need of tablename

Answer (score 18):

Solved it via @Yannics answer at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60924664/5804947

This also avoids using [`extra`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#extra) which should be "a last resort" due to Django docs.

```
from django.db.models import F, Func, Value, CharField

qs.annotate(
  formatted_date=Func(
    F('created_at'),
    Value('DD-MM-YYYY HH:MM:SS'),
    function='to_char',
    output_field=CharField()
  )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think `values()` function would anything related to formatting datetime result. But why does that bother you? Can't you convert them to proper format when you try to display them? If you try to render them in the template, django has template filter `date` for formatting your datetime value: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/templates/builtins/#date

Comment: true, for display I'm doing the same but my usecase is to write the data in to pdf / csv, which I want to do with out iterations

Comment: That's not true, as long as you are rendering/processing the data, you are always iterating the queryset, so even your solution works, you didn't gain anything. On the other side, you solution made the code less readable and relying on underlying database, If you change the database your code might break so it's not portable.