# Django ORM to retrieve month name from date time

Tags: sql, django, django-queryset, django-orm

I need to retrieve month name with sum total price of the corresponding month.
Here is my order table sample

[image: Database Sample]

My try is:

```
month_wise_sales = Order.objects\
.annotate(month=ExtractMonth('created_at'))\
.values('month')\
.annotate(total_sales=Sum('total_price'))
```

It will return

```
<QuerySet [{'month': 7, 'total_sales': Decimal('138400.00')}, {'month': 9, 'total_sales': Decimal('1150.00')}]>
```

My desire is something like this

```
[{'month': July, 'total_sales': Decimal('138400.00')}, {'month': September, 'total_sales': Decimal('1150.00')}]
```

How to resolve this?

Comment: possible https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38570258/how-to-get-django-queryset-results-with-formatted-datetime-field

Comment: do you need o/p in response or in template ?

Comment: template @HemanthSP

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This work fine for me.
Working query

```
month_wise_sales = Order.objects\
.annotate(month=Cast('created_at', DateField()))\
.values('month')\
.annotate(total_sales=Sum('total_price'))
```

and then in template use this

```
{{ monthly_sales.month | date:"M"}}
```

By this, I will get the sum of total price with month name.