# how to get month and year (Jan, 2020) from datetimefield in queryset object in django python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-views, django-queryset

I have a table with field id, Img, UploadDate and many more fields.

this is how `models.py` looks

```
class ImgDetails(models.Model):
    Img = models.ImageField(upload_to='media')
    Category = models.ForeignKey(CategoryList, default=1, on_delete=models.SET_DEFAULT, null=False)
    keywords = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    User = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    Valid = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    UploadDate = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

In `views.py`, I want to fetch id, Img and UploadDate but in UploadDate field(which is of type datetimefield) i want to get only month and year how can i get it .

I have tried:

`collectMonthYear = ImgDetails.objects.filter(User_id=user.id,Valid=True).annotate(Date=('UploadDate').strftime("%m-%Y")).values('id','Img','Date')`

this raise error: `'str' object has no attribute 'strftime'`

can anyone help me with that. how can i fetch the data with 'UploadDate' field having month and year only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone for your help.

I did this to achieve it - I first get the value in queryset

```
queryset = ImgDetails.objects.filter(User_id=user.id,Valid=True).annotate(month=ExtractMonth('UploadDate'),year=ExtractYear('UploadDate'))
```

and then convert it into list of dictionary by concatenating month and year in a single key

```
queryset_value = []
print(queryset)

for result in queryset:
    queryset_value.append({'id': result.id, 'Img': result.Img.url, 'UploadDate' : str(result.month)+"-"+str(result.year)})

print(queryset_value)
```

Output:

```
[{'id': 24, 'Img': '/media/1-cover_bg_2.jpg', 'UploadDate': '7-2020'}, {'id': 26, 'Img': '/media/1-person_woman_1.jpg', 'UploadDate': '7-2020'}, {'id': 27, 'Img': '/
media/1-person_woman_3.jpg', 'UploadDate': '7-2020'}, {'id': 29, 'Img': '/media/1-person_man_2.jpg', 'UploadDate': '7-2020'}, {'id': 30, 'Img': '/media/1-person_man_
3.jpg', 'UploadDate': '7-2020'}, {'id': 31, 'Img': '/media/1-person_woman_2.jpg', 'UploadDate': '7-2020'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep using the same logic, you can change str to date using date() function.

Comment: while change str to date(). error: ```an integer is required (got type str)```

Answer (score 0):

You can check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38570258/how-to-get-django-queryset-results-with-formatted-datetime-field) to get it done. However, you can do the formatting after you get the result from `queryset` like below:

```
queryset = ImgDetails.objects.filter(User_id=user.id,Valid=True)
for result in queryset:
  dt = result.UploadDate.strftime("%m-%Y")
```

Which way you want to follow will depend on your use case.

Comment: this code is returning, output: 07-2020. i think it is only storing data of date column and and every time the loop iterate the pervious value get override

Comment: @im.variable, yes, I showed how you can iterate over the queryset and extract the DateTime with format. If you need all the data, you can use a `list` and append to it inside the loop.

Comment: thanx for your help. but i did it in a different way. i have also posted how i did it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use django inbuilt database functions.

```
from django.db.models.functions import ExtractMonth, ExtractYear

ImgDetails.objects.filter(User_id=user.id,Valid=True).annotate(month=ExtractMonth('UploadDate'),year=ExtractYear('UploadDate'))
```

Follow this [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/database-functions/#datefield-extracts) for more details.

Comment: I don't know why this answer marked from acceptance to un-accept after a month because this answer contains import and not have a print statement. No offense but curious to know the reason.