# Format datefield in Django Report with reportlab

Tags: django, reportlab

In my Django App I have an app to generate a reportlab report based on simpledoctemplates. To create the table inside the report I read the data with a value_list query to handover the queryset to the data variable for the table.

```
teilnehmer_alle = Teilnehmer.objects.filter(
                        teilnehmer_sprung__gt=0,
                        teilnehmer_geburtsjahr__range=[riege.riege_ab,
                                                       riege.riege_bis]).values_list('id',
                                                                                     'teilnehmer_name',
                                                                                     'teilnehmer_vorname',
                                                                                     'teilnehmer_verein__verein_name_kurz',
                                                                                     'teilnehmer_geburtsjahr',
                                                                                     'teilnehmer_sprung'
                                                                                     )
```

and here is the handover to the table:

```
headers = ['Start-Nr.', 'Nachname', 'Vorname', 'Verein', 'Jahrgang', 'Meldung', 'A-Note', 'B-Note',
                           'Summe']
                table_data = [headers] + [list(row) + [''] * (len(headers) - len(row)) for row in teilnehmer_alle]
                if table_data:
                    t = Table(table_data)
                    content.append(t)
```

everything works fine, but the value of the 'teilnehmer_geburtsjahr' isn't in the format I want to use. Currently it is 'YYYY-mm-dd' but I want only the year information in the report.

Is there a way to change this inside the queryset? Or is there another solution?

Any ideas?

I'have tried to change the queryset without "values" or "value_list" but I didn't find a solution to change the format before I create the table.

Comment: You can refer verified answer of this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38570258/how-to-get-django-queryset-results-with-formatted-datetime-field