# Extract on date : django.db.utils.OperationalError: near "None": syntax error

Tags: django

I try to format the date in a query, but I got an error whentrying to extract the year, the month...

This occurs on sqlLite and Postgres.

Django version : 1.11.4

```
>>> users = User.objects.all()
>>> users.annotate(year=Cast(ExtractYear('date_joined'), CharField()))

return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "None": syntax error
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's really weird. It couldn't cast even ID of users like:
`users.annotate(year=Cast('id', CharField()))`

**Solution:**

Try using `TextField` like:
`users.annotate(year=Cast(ExtractYear('date_joined'), TextField()))`
instead of `CharField`

Comment: Indeed, replacing the CharField with the TextField did the trick, thanks.