# Django: Group by date over a datetime field

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

I have for example a model like this:

```
class Transaction(models.Model):
    amount = models.FloatField()
    seller = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='sells', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    buyer = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='purchased', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

I want to group by all transactions seperated by each date and find some of them. If the `created_at` is of type `DateField` I could simply find the count on each day by this query:

```
Transaction.objects..values('created_at').annotate(count=Count('created_at_date')
```

But this **doesn't work** `DateTimeFeilds`.

My question is how can i find total count of transactions for each date for this model type.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The following will work for **django 2.1** and above.

```
 Transaction.objects.values('created_at__date').annotate(count=Count('id')).values('created_at__date', 'count').order_by('created_at__date')
```

You need to use `__date` after the name for lookup and need to put an `order_by` at the end.

Not sure about the previous django versions.

Comment: This does not work with MySql, mysql return 'created_at__date' as None

Comment: @MasZero - were you able to solve this None issue in MySQL?

Comment: Nope even switching connector @AnuragRana

Answer (score 0):

I had a slightly different problem, in that I wanted to group by a partial date, but I think you should be able to adapt this to work with your requirements (Django 3.2+). Bonus: works with MySQL.

```
queryset = Viewlog.objects.all().values(
    year_month=Func(
        F('date'),
        Value('%Y-%m'),
        function='DATE_FORMAT',
        output_field=CharField())
    ).annotate(total=Count('year_month')).order_by('-year_month').distinct()
```

For your particular use:

```
Transaction.objects.all().values(year_month_day=Func(
        F('date'),
        Value('%Y-%m-%d'),
        function='DATE_FORMAT',
        output_field=CharField())
    ).annotate(total=Count('year_month_day')).order_by('-year_month_day').distinct()
```

For other databases you will need to change the `function='DATE_FORMAT'`

Adapted from: [conversion of datetime Field to string in django queryset.values_list()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17085898/conversion-of-datetime-field-to-string-in-django-queryset-values-list/60924664#60924664)