# django queryset with __date returns Nones

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have a django queryset where I want to group by `created_at` date value (`created_at` is a datetime field).

```py
(Activity.objects
    .values('created_at__date')
    .annotate(count=Count('id'))
    .values('created_at__date', 'count')
 )
```

I am following the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54037745/1056460) which makes sense. However, the query returns `None` for all `created_at__date` values. When I change it to `created_at` it shows the actual value.

The generated SQL query:

```
SELECT 
   django_datetime_cast_date("activity"."created_at", 'UTC', 'UTC'), 
   COUNT("activity"."id") AS "count" 
FROM 
   "activity" 
GROUP BY 
   django_datetime_cast_date("activity"."created_at", 'UTC', 'UTC')
```

I am working with local sqlite3 database, some sample records from DB (the other columns in the table are removed):

```
2,2021-07-30T11:44:09.984439+00:00
3,2021-07-30T11:44:29.217916+00:00
4,2021-07-30T11:44:43.598702+00:00
5,2021-08-03T20:53:48.482419+00:00
6,2021-08-04T22:19:52.810907+00:00
7,2021-08-05T17:25:29.646553+00:00
8,2021-08-05T17:25:33.425523+00:00
9,2021-08-05T17:26:22.169369+00:00
10,2021-08-05T17:50:26.585485+00:00
11,2021-08-10T16:20:38.839126+00:00
12,2021-08-10T17:38:00.557487+00:00
13,2021-08-11T16:09:30.470890+00:00
14,2021-08-11T16:09:34.164904+00:00
15,2021-08-12T15:43:18.819458+00:00
16,2021-08-12T16:19:30.123575+00:00
18,2021-08-15T12:55:20.660137+00:00
24,2021-08-18T18:21:12.153480+00:00
25,2021-08-18T19:18:37.432911+00:00
```

Comment: Is this a MySQL database?

Comment: It is sqlite3 DB, will add to the question as well

Comment: your code is fine. it is working as expected. can share sample records in your database?

Comment: added sample data

Comment: I got it.. the error is that the data in the table is migrated from postgres, and sqlite can't get the date from this format as it expects `2021-11-29 12:40:19.105073` format.

Comment: I opened an issue for it https://github.com/simonw/db-to-sqlite/issues/38
@Neeraj, you can post it as an answer and I'll accept.

Comment: @DanielM, Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is sqlite3 database can not store timezone information as it does not support built-in date and/or time. And since the sample date contains timezone information, sqlite3 is unable to extract date from the datetime field, and showing None.

correct format for sqlite3

2021-11-29 12:40:20.021350

Comment: Am using MySQL but with the same issue, so, I'll assume this works both ways. (Went from SQLite to MySQL, but same issue as OP shows.)