# Having a Django serializer return two flat lists

Tags: django, django-serializer

With a serializer like this...

```
class MyPriceSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    prices = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_prices(self, obj):
        return obj.prices.values_list('price', flat=True)

class ChartData(RetrieveAPIView):
    queryset = Market.objects.all()
    authentication_classes = []
    permission_classes = []
    serializer_class = MyPriceSerializer
```

...I can pick up a flat list like this on the other end:

```
{
    "prices": [
        0.52,
        0.55,
        ...
        0.94,
        0.93
    ]
}
```

And if I change the serlializer to `return obj.prices.values_list('price_date', flat=True)`, I can get this:

```
{
    "prices": [
        "2019-07-22T15:19:02.924811Z",
        "2019-07-22T15:19:02.924811Z",
        ...
        "2019-07-22T15:58:41.337422Z",
        "2019-07-22T16:04:16.753870Z"
    ]
}
```

But **is it possible to get both (as below) in one serializer**, so that I can pick up the result in one Ajax call in a template?

```
{
    "prices": [
        0.52,
        0.55,
        ...
        0.94,
        0.93
    ]

    "price_dates": [
        "2019-07-22T15:19:02.924811Z",
        "2019-07-22T15:19:02.924811Z",
        ...
        "2019-07-22T15:58:41.337422Z",
        "2019-07-22T16:04:16.753870Z"
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just add another `SerializerMethodField`:

```
class MyPriceSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    prices = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    price_dates = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_prices(self, obj):
        return obj.prices.values_list('price', flat=True)

    def get_price_dates(self, obj):
        return obj.prices.values_list('price_date', flat=True)
```

If you add [`prefetch_related`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) to queryset this allows you to add as many field from `prices` as you want without extra sql query:

```
class ChartData(RetrieveAPIView):
    queryset = Market.objects.all().prefetch_related('prices')
    authentication_classes = []
    permission_classes = []
    serializer_class = MyPriceSerializer
```

Comment: By the way, is there an easy way to truncate the strings returned by `get_price_dates` from (e.g.) `"2019-07-22T15:58:41.337422Z"` to `"2019-07-22 15:58"`?

Comment: @kh_one look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/48503805/641249

Comment: Thanks! I'm on Postgres, so this ended up working: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18749861/5674156