# Django parse date to dd-mm-yyyy in QuerySet

Tags: sql-server, django, django-rest-framework, django-queryset

I have the following QuerySet to retrieve all dates with a count of records out of a SQL Server database.

```
    def get_amount_per_day(self):
        return self.extra(select={'time': 'CONVERT(DATE, starttime)'}).values(
            'time').annotate(amount=Count('starttime')).order_by('time')
```

The output is:

```
{
        "time": "2019-03-07T00:00:00",
        "amount": 216
    },
    {
        "time": "2019-03-07T01:00:00",
        "amount": 178
    }
}
```

But I want to parse the date to `07-03-2019`, does anyone know how I can achieve this?

I tried to convert the date to `varchar` but then the `order_by` doesn't work correctly. It has to be of type `DATE`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [**`Cast`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/database-functions/#cast). For example:

```
from django.db.models.functions import Cast
from django.db.models import DateField

YourModel.objects.annotate(start_date=Cast('starttime', DateField()))
```

### Update

You can try like this using [**`database functions`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/database-functions/):

```
from django.db.models.functions import ExtractDay, ExtractMonth, ExtractYear

YourModel.objects.annotate(
    year=ExtractYear('starttime'),
    month=ExtractMonth('starttime'),
    day=ExtractDay('starttime')
).annotate(start_date=F('date')+'-'+F('month')+'-'+F('year')).values('start_date')
```

### Untested code

[Based on this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55473906/2696165), you can try like this:

```
YourModel.objects.annotate(start_date=ExpressionWrapper(
        Func(F('starttime'), Value('%d-%m-%Y'), function='DATE_FORMAT'), output_field=CharField()
    ))
```

Comment: The problem is not to cast it to DateField, it is already a DateField. The problem is that it doesn't return the wanted format.

Comment: The untested code doesn't work with SQL Server, `DATE_FORMAT` is not a function.
The other posibiltiy returns 2024 instead of `2-3-2019`. It adds all the number up to 2024 but I don't know why