# how to extract only day from timestamp in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I want to get a specific date like "8" out of (2021-8-3) but it's showing like this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D61J1.png)

how can I extract the specific date?

```
 usertime = User.objects.filter(groups__name = 'patient').values('date_joined').annotate(date_only=Cast('date_joined', DateField()))
```

Comment: to extract only day from a datetimefield  try date_joined__day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from django.db.models import F, Func,Value, CharField

usertime = (User.objects.filter(groups__name = 'patient').values('date_joined')
            .annotate(date_only=Func(
                F('date_joined'),
                Value('MM'),
                function='to_char',
                output_field=CharField()
            )
                     ).values('date_only'))
```

Try this,
got a reference from @Yannics answer at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60924664/5804947

you can further use `YYYY` / `DD` for years/date respectively under the `Value` field and works fine when the PostgreSQL database is used.

**ANOTHER METHOD**

```
from django.db.models.functions import Extract
usertime = User.objects.filter(groups__name = 'patient').values('date_joined').annotate(date_only=Extract('date_joined', 'month'))
```

Comment: to_char is for postgresql if am not mistaken.as a result it doesn't work on sqlite3 which is my database. what should I use for sqlite3?

Comment: Can you try `convert`, I think that's the one used in sqlite3. I don't have much idea about sqlite3. Sorry

Comment: `usertime = (User.objects.filter(groups__name='patient').values('date_joined')
                .annotate(date_only=Func(
                    F('date_joined'),
                    Value('DD'),
                    function='strftime',
                    output_field=CharField()
                )).values('date_only'))`  

showing <QuerySet [{'date_only': None}, {'date_only': None}, {'date_only': None}, {'date_only': None}]>

Comment: try below code snippet

`
 usertime =  User.objects.filter(groups__name = 'patient').values('date_joined').annotate(date_only=Cast('date_joined', DateField()))
for u in usertime:
    u['date_only'] = u['date_only'].month
print(usertime)
`

It's a workaround, but I think you will achieve what you wanted.
this simply loops through each instance in queryset and reassigns month in place of the date.

Comment: `usertime = User.objects.filter(groups__name = 'patient').values('date_joined').annotate(date_only=Cast('date_joined', DateField())) 
    days = []
    for u in usertime: 
        u = u['date_only'].day 
        print(u)
        days.append(u) `

this works fine. thank you