# Django F-expression transform output value

Tags: django, django-queryset

I'm using an F-expression to get a foreign key object's date value. But it returns a datetime object as the date. How can I transform it to 'YYYY-MM-DD' format?

```
from django.db.models import F

PendingRequest.objects.all().values('id', creation_date=F('agreement__created_at__date'))

output:
<QuerySet [
{'id': 1, 'creation_date': datetime.date(2022, 10, 16)},
{'id': 2, 'creation_date': datetime.date(2022, 10, 16)},
...
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [conversion of datetime Field to string in django queryset.values\_list()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17085898/conversion-of-datetime-field-to-string-in-django-queryset-values-list)

Comment: Please *don't* use the database for string/date formatting.

Answer (score 1):

> But it returns a datetime object as the date. How can I transform it to 'YYYY-MM-DD' format?

Please, *don't* use the database to format dates or strings. Databases should not be used to *render* data. Databases are used to store, retrieve and aggregate data.

It is the task of the templates, serializers, etc. to provide the data in an accessible format. For example in the template, you can format a date with the [**`|date`** template filter <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/templates/builtins/#date):

```
{{ my_date|date:"Y-m-d" }}
```

Django also can [*serialize data* <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/serialization/#serializing-data), if you serialize it to JSON, it will also encod it in that format:

```
>>> json.dumps(date(2023, 10, 20), cls=DjangoJSONEncoder)
'"2023-10-20"'
```